# AsyncTask not cancelling upon cancel(boolean)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having some issues cancelling an AsyncTask. I am fairly new to Android programming, so I've probably made a typo somewhere.

What happens when i press the cancel button is as follows:

- Invoking cancel(true) within the cancelButton's onClick event appears to modify the variable used by isCancelled(), so that the for-loopin doInBackground will be terminated by the break statement. However:
- onCancelled(String) is not invoked.

I get expected behavior if I don't press cancel, so the question only concerns the onCancelled method.

The code is as follows:

```
public class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
//Variables to be used by onPreExecute, onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate
//and onCancelled, as they can operate on the UI thread.
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button submitButton;
private Button cancelButton;
private TextView resultText;
private int max;

//Constructor initializing the field variables.

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    submitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    resultText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
    resultText.setText("Working on item 1 of " + max);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancel(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String ... strings) {

    for(int count = 0; count < strings.length; ++count) {
        if(isCancelled()) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publishProgress(count);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    return "Task completed: " + strings[0];
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cancelButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    resultText.setText(result);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer ... values) {
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    //don't mind the line under, some testing...
    resultText.setText("Working on item " + (values[0]+2) + " of " + max);
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled(String result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cancelButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    resultText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    resultText.setText("Canceled.");
}
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why onCancelled(String) is not invoked? I've been looking for similar questions on StackOwerFlow, but haven't found any that answer my problem :-)

The AsyncTask is started by the following Activity (upon pressing the asyncTaskSubmit button):

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private Button asyncTaskSubmit;
    private Button asyncTaskCancel;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;
    private static final int MAX = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //call super, initialize fieldvariables with findViewById.
        asyncTaskSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                String [] doJobs = new String[MAX];
                //dummydata
                for(int x = 0; x < doJobs.length; x++) {
                    doJobs[x] = text;
                }
                new CustomAsyncTask(
                    progressBar,
                    asyncTaskSubmit,
                    asyncTaskCancel,
                    textView,
                    MAX
                ).execute(doJobs);      
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Additional information:

- SDK (min): 16
- SDK (target): 23
- Emulator device: Google nexus 5 (API 23)

Thanks in advance!

-Superdids

Comment: rather not typo as using `@Override` with `protected void onCancelled` would cause a compile time error if overrided method would not fit the base method ... how do you start this async task?

Comment: Instead of using isCancelled() use a Boolean Variable to keep track of running status and make it false in onCancelled(result);

Comment: i bet on `new CustomAsyncTask().doInBackground("some string")` or `new CustomAsyncTask().execute()`  .... first one obviously will not call onCancelled ... second, will throw index out of bounds on `strings[0]`

Comment: Selvin: Yeah thats true :-) I've also added the Activity as well now to show how the AsyncTask is executed.

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tiny modification seems to provide the expected results. I changed the argument of cancel(boolean) from true to false:

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //cancel(true);
        cancel(false);
    }
});
```

As the argument (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) states:

- True if the thread executing this task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed to complete.

At least as of my implementation, this implies that the doInBackground method won't return if I pass true as argument in cancel(..).

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/